# Which ios font support both text and emoji characters?

Tags: ios, emoji

This is the first time i am handling the emoji keyboard for my application. 
        I am using custom font to display the text and the emoji characters. I want to know the ios font which support both the text and the emoji characters to display in my app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a special font to support emoji. Just use whatever font you use to display your "normal" characters and iOS will automatically switch to the `AppleColorEmoji` font to display any "emoji" characters.

If you want more info about what font to use, http://iosfonts.com/ is a great site.